# Flink cancel command does not cancel a running task

Tags: apache-flink

I am working on a remote cluster. I have a task which runs for long time and it seems it has a problem, so I canceled the task via web client and also even command line. Unfortunately the canceling states also takes for long time and one of the slot in the tasks managers remains occupied.

Is there any way to release the occupied slots, or terminated the the task currently in the canceling state? other than restarting the cluster?

Comment: If the task does not react to the cancel call via the web interface and the command line client, then there is no other way than killing the corresponding `TaskManager`. You can either do that manually and bringing up a new `TaskManager` via the `taskmanager.sh` script or restart the cluster.

Comment: Which tasks are not cancelling? I think all build in operators in Flink (such as the data sources) should react to cancelling signals immediately.

Comment: I submit my program which contain variety of commands to a remote cluster. The submitted job does not output the result in a normal time, in this case I cancel the job via web client!